# Encoding.UTF8.GetString working wrong with data receive from socket

Tags: c#, sockets

These days I'm facing a problem with encoding string from an array of byte.
I use a socket to receive the data from server to a buffer, then I create a `MemoryStream` to read data from this buffer to a tempBuffer with a fixed length 30 to later `GetString` from tempBuffer.

```
byte tempBuff = new byte[30];
streamReader.Read(tempBuff, 0, 30);
string moTaSkill = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempBuff);
```

The I use a textBox to display this string as below:

```
tbSkill.Text = moTaSkill;
```

It always display wrong on the text box:

1. When debug I see moTaSkill = "SKill of the hero"
2. When display on the textBox it just "Skill of" or sometimes "Skill " or "Skill of the"

I tried to create the tempBuffer with the length equals the length of string I will receive. But no success.

Can any one tell me some solution to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems.  You are forgetting to pay attention to the return value of the Read() call.  It tells you how many actual bytes got copied into *tempBuf*.  Which you should then use in the GetString() method so that you can avoid converting zeros.

Second problem is that a TCP connection provides a network *stream*, not a packet.  It is quite unpredictable how many bytes you'll get for each Read() call.  Again, the return value tells you this.  It will only match the number of bytes that were transmitted by the server by accident.  You need to keep calling Read() until you get them all.  Chief problem with that is that you don't necessarily know when the reading is done.  The server will need to pass some extra data so that the receiver knows.  Like sending the string length first.

Answer (score 1):

We will need more code, but I'll tell you what is happening.

Your TextBox is using the standard windows controls. The standard windows controls stop writing at the first `\0` character (`nul` in C/C++). This because they use "C String" that are nul terminated array of characters. Your string contains those, probably because you copy it wrongly somewhere. The Visual Studio shows the full string because he can show eve `\0` characters. Try doing: `int ix = moTaSkill.IndexOf('\0');`

Comment: Thank you all for your help, the reason is null character at the end of string. I did somewrong when copy data to the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you assume Read fills your buffer; this is not safe. You must call Read and check the return value to see how many bytes were read. All you are guaranteed is <=0 (for EOF) or > 0 and <= count (if not EOF). This often means looping, adding an offset and reducing the count each time. To help with this, it is common to indicate (first) the length of the data to follow, so you know when to stop. You can also use EOF to stop, but obviously only if the channel isn't a long-running 2-way conversation.

You should also only attempt to encode the real data; if 14 bytes were read, you must tell the encoder to only look at 14 bytes, even if the buffer is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the flush command in your code since all the buffer should be reset.

upload the code where you fill the buffer